# Skype и уведомления

Tags: skype

Имеется небольшой хостинг, основная поддержка через скайп, все уведомления сейчас шлются на мыло, а-ля: сервер отпал, сервер был отакован, просрочена оплата, etc...

Решил погрызить скайп и слать туда. Вижу, что api отсутствует (отключилось/умерло), каким образом можно взаимодействовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API есть, но нужно держать запущенный скайп. Есть скайп без gui (headless skype), но этот проект был в полузакрытой бете и его похоже прикрыли.

К тому же скайп не является ИМ (сервисом быстрой доставки сообщений), поэтому он полностью не подходит для данной задачи.

(да, скайп иногда не доставляет сообщение, иногда доставляет сообщения через большой промежуток времени и тому подобное)

Что делать? можно использовать жаббер, а для особо важных событий - смс. И мыло - это очень хороший способ.

**Обновление**

skype kit (это скайп без gui) - [прикрыли](https://support.skype.com/ru/faq/FA12322/pravda-li-cto-prekrasaetsa-podderzka-skypekit).
desktop api также [прикрыли](http://blogs.skype.com/2013/11/06/feature-evolution-and-support-for-the-skype-desktop-api/).

Есть проект по реверсу протокола, но его прикрыли.

> Запущенный Скайп не столь большая проблема

на сервере? ещё какая проблема:)

Comment: Запущенный Скайп ни столь большая проблема, а можно ссылочку на апи?

Comment: Выделить один серверок с иксами и скайпом, у меня возможность есть. А по поводу жабера и смс, смс есть, жабера нет, но скайп, не моя инициатива) но делать нужно(хотябы попытаться)

Comment: Лучше отказывайтесь. Раньше оно работало (более того, у меня даже был проект с этим всем), но сейчас оно практически не работает (нужно использовать старые версии скайпклиента, которые не работают нормально).

Со скайпом на сервере есть одна маленькая проблема - в один момент он понимает, что он на сервере, и канал в интернет большой. Значит можно стать супернодой! А это значит, что количество траффика через сервер сильно возрастет (именно сильно, вначале гигабайты в день, а потом и больше). Можно конечно фаерволами подрезать, но это, опять же, нетривиальная задача.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за отклик, но все же, во фри тайм погугля, пока нашел что-то на питоне, буду тестить.